# Why do my html img disappears suddenly and i need to clear caches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I said in the title, I have an HTML `img` tag that displays a normal `.svg` image. The image is juste a picture of a television, inside the screen of this television I want to display a slider (that I've created).

The image size is 128Ko.

This is the part of the code:

```
<div class="screen-img">
  <ul class="list-img-onScreen">
    <li class="img-1"><img src="img/img1.png"></div></li>
    <li class="img-2"><img src="img/img2.png"></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<img src="css/img/television.svg" class="img-TV">
```

What I want is to display `ul` of images inside a picture of a television (which is the `television.svg`). when I've first seen the result on chrome browser it was awesome, I've got the television and inside it's screen there was my slider of pictures defiling one after one. But after working on this page for about one week (adding other stuff in this page) I've realized that the television.svg disappears, the slider of pictures still there but not the television. When I clear caches the television appears.

Comment: Man just from the way that sounds I think you are probably going to want to add your css. And when you say clear caches do you mean it comes back when your refresh the screen?

Comment: Do you have a link where we could view your page ? (is it already on a web server ?) 
The code you provide is too poor to understand if there's a problem somewhere.
But just to understand, why you don't use your television image as background-image of your div ?

Comment: @wuno yes exactly when i clear caches, i refresh and the television re-appears again, i'll edit the question to add css i'm sorry

Comment: @Gianca i'll test the background idea yes and no the website is not yet on a web server

Comment: I think you have to put online your site (on a webserver) to realize if this problem is just something on your local system or is a real problem... It's an uncommon problem and it could be just on your local machine.

Comment: I am pretty confident the new images are on top of the tv image.. its probably just in the background. to test this check the dom and target the tv element. Move it around and is if you can get it to pop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the image as the background of your div ?

Look here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tndm9j6/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="bgimg">
    Here your slide show...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bgimg {
  width: 280px;
  height: 203px;
  background-image: url('http://pngimg.com/upload/tv_PNG477.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gianca , i can't say if the television will disappear in the futur (because with my first img tag on html the television appears at first times) so maybe my problem is the img tag on html after the ul ?

Comment: It's very difficult to give you an answer without see the entire code. I suggest you to upload everything on a webserver or to paste here all your project (all the html, css and javascript in case you use it).
Because we need to replicate the problem to fix it.